# Userforms for setting multiple filter criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

I have 6 userforms which pop up and ask you to select the variables that you wish to sort:

1. ClientFilter
2. CostCenterFilter
3. UtilityFilter
4. TypeOfWorkfilter
5. AnalystFilter
6. ProjMgrFilter

Inside each one it uses if statements to for each variable.

```
Sub UpdateCF()
    Integer_CF = -1

    If AU_CF.Value = True Then
        Add_CF String_CF, "AU"
        Range("$B$6:$AU$68").AutoFilter  _
              Field:=2, Criteria1:=String_CF,   _
              Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If AULaw_CF.Value = True Then
        Add_CF String_CF, "AULAW"
        Range("$B$6:$AU$68").AutoFilter  _
              Field:=2, Criteria1:=String_CF,   _
              Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
    ... 

End Sub

Sub Add_CF(String_CF() As String, NewValue As String)
    Integer_CF = Integer_CF + 1
    ReDim Preserve String_CF(Integer_CF)
    String_CF(Integer_CF) = NewValue
End Sub
```

This works fine except I want to be able to sort on multiple fields. For example I would like to be to use The Client Filter and then select a variable then use the Cost Center Userform to be able to have both sorts enabled at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you think you have a problem - you can use your same approach as above, but add the filter to a different field. That will filter on both.

For example (obviously you will need to adapt to your situation):

```
Sub blah()

    Dim currentFilters_FirstField
    Dim currentFilters_SecondField
    Dim field1_Option1, field1_Option2, field2_Option1, field2_Option2 'just an example
    Dim rng As Range

    field1_Option1 = True
    field1_Option2 = True
    field2_Option1 = True
    field2_Option2 = False

    'prepare your filters from the menu etc
    If field1_Option1 Then appendFilterValue currentFilters_FirstField, "AU"
    If field1_Option2 Then appendFilterValue currentFilters_FirstField, "AULAW"
    If field2_Option1 Then appendFilterValue currentFilters_SecondField, "Whatever1"
    If field2_Option2 Then appendFilterValue currentFilters_SecondField, "Whatever2"

    Set rng = Range("A1:D100") ' range for the filtering etc
    rng.AutoFilter 1, currentFilters_FirstField, xlFilterValues
    rng.AutoFilter 2, currentFilters_SecondField, xlFilterValues 'note the different field this is applying to

End Sub

Sub appendFilterValue(ByRef currentFilters, newFilter)

    If IsArray(currentFilters) Then
        ReDim Preserve currentFilters(0 To UBound(currentFilters) + 1)
    Else
        ReDim currentFilters(0 To 0)
    End If

    currentFilters(UBound(currentFilters)) = newFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Would I put this in a module and call it from the User forum or place it in each userform

Comment: @MichaelDowney It depends on your object model. Some people like to put 'business' logic inside their userforms. I prefer to use the user forms to work out "arguments" e.g. for your case - a property indicating whether the AULAW filter should be on is set to true then the 'main' procedure that called the user form picks up the desired argument from these properties and calls a relevant procedure that actuall sets the filters. This way you centralise the 'business logic' and each special filter user form works in the same way.

Comment: @MichaelDowney also, you can just use the same principle as you already are working with -> the same can be used to set a filter based on multiple fields. My code above is just a demo. You are already correctly making the filter value arrays etc :)